# Angular + Rails: Angular cannot find controller function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

**Problem:** I wrote an Angular / Rails app and when I attempt to access a Rails controller function from the Angular controller, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: tasks.moveOrder is not a function`, but all other functions on that page are available

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
def index
    respond_with Task.all
end

def create
    respond_with Task.create(task_params)
end

def destroy
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    task.destroy

    respond_with task
end

def show
    respond_with Task.find(params[:id])
end

def moveOrder # This is the function that cannot be found
    task = Task.find(task_id)
    task.position = pos

    respond_with task
end

def up_completion
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    task.increment!(:completion)

    respond_with task
end

def down_completion
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    task.decrement!(:completion)

    respond_with task
end

private
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :completion, :importance, :steps, :clicked, :position)
end
```

Each of these functions have routes and each function is called through my angular controller:

**MainCtrl.js**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'tasks',
function($scope, tasks){

    $scope.tasks = tasks.tasks;
    $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

    $scope.addTask = function() {
        var taskPosition = tasks.tasks.length + 1;
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        tasks.create({ // This call to the .rb file works!
            title: $scope.title, 
            importance: $scope.importance,
            completion: 0,  
            steps: $scope.steps,
            clicked: false,
            position: taskPosition // puts position as field in db (needs to be updated when dragged)
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.importance = '';
        $scope.steps = '';
    };

    $scope.moveTask = function(start_pos, end_pos) {
        $.get( "http://localhost:3000/tasks.json" )
        .done(function( data ) {
                var task_id = data[start_pos].id;
                tasks.moveOrder(task_id, end_pos) // This call to the .rb file fails!
        });
    };

    ...
```

**app.js**

```
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                taskPromise: ['tasks', function(tasks){
                    return tasks.getAll();
                }]
            }
    })

        .state('tasks', {
            url: '/tasks/{id}',
            templateUrl: 'tasks/_tasks.html',
            controller: 'TasksCtrl'
        });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

Is the function call failing because I wrote something incorrectly or is there some other issue altogether?

Comment: You can't call server-side functions from client side code. (Allowing this would be a serious security vulnerability.) Use an AJAX request instead.

Comment: Then why am I able to call the other functions? in the `tasks_controller.rb` file (i.e. `tasks.create`, `tasks.up_completion`, `tasks.down_completion` (not shown), etc.?

Comment: Touché. I'm not actually familiar with Angular, but my guess is it has something to do with `create`, `show`, `update`, and `destroy` being mapped to standard REST routes in Rails by default. If that is indeed the cause, then `up_completion` and `down_completion` shouldn't work either, just `create`, `show`, `update`, and `destroy`. Regardless, you aren't calling those methods directly. Somewhere along the line, AJAX is almost certainly involved (or maybe websockets. Like I said, I'm not actually familiar with Angular), it's just being handled automatically by Angular. Just an observation.

Comment: I agree that I'm probably not calling them directly (I'm still new to backend processes), I just can't seem to figure out why every function other than `moveOrder` works

Comment: @JeremyThomas - You are not calling those functions. What you do is you are calling javascript function, which makes an AJAX call to your API server. Most likely you are using `angular-rails-resource` which automatically creates those functions for you to handle all CRUD operations (so methods like show or index are available), but you need to add all your custom methods manually. Your `task` factory is crucial here.  Please refer to the documentation of whatever library you use.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation for [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). RESTful routes are provided (thus `create`, `get`, etc. will work), but you need to explicitly define additional actions, which you will map to the routes corresponding to the controller actions. You would do something like this:

```
app.factory('Tasks', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/tasks/:id', null,
  {
    'moveOrder': { method:'POST', url: 'route_to_your_action' },
    'otherAction': { url: 'route_to_your_action' }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: my apologies for not including my `app.js` file.  I've added it above

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were using $resource… That said, where do you define task_id and pos in your rails controller, in the moveOrder action? Shouldn't you get them from the request's parameters?

Comment: Yes, which I cannot seem to get working.  I'm fooling around with `$resource` now and hopefully I'll figure it out.  Would the missing params cause the function to not be found?

Comment: Not the missing params, but a server error (http status 500) potentially yes. You can check the server log to see what is happening.